# Raster algebra (subtract) changes extent of output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, raster-calculator

I have a tool that calculates volume of a portion of a raster DTM. I first clip a portion of the entire raster then fill it. I then subtract the clipped original from the filled raster. My problem is that if my project only has the DTM as part of it, it works fine. However if I include a much larger DTM in the Table of Contents, it doesn't, even though the larger raster is not referenced by the code. What happens is that the difference raster now has the extents of the larger raster and the differences are now near the upper left corner, instead of being aligned with the clipped & filled rasters. So under the first condition, the difference raster is 462x365, but in the second case, it balloons to 39000x39000, the extent of the second DTM.

I have included a set extent statement, but that seems to make no difference. Below is the offending part of the code. OK up to `rastercalc_temp`, but that raster has the aberrant dimensions.

```py
Input_DEM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Aguada_rectangular_boundaries = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Aguada_geodatabase = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Set Geoprocessing environments
tempEnvironment0 = arcpy.env.extent
arcpy.env.extent = Aguada_rectangular_boundaries
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\Users\William\Desktop\ModelBuilder\Scratch\Aguada_scratch.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\William\Desktop\ModelBuilder\Scratch\Aguada_scratch.gdb"

# Local variables:
Clipped_raster = "Clipped_raster"

# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_management(Input_DEM, "", Clipped_raster, Aguada_rectangular_boundaries, "-3.402823e+038", "ClippingGeometry", "MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

# Process: Fill
Fill_NCALM = arcpy.sa.Fill(Clipped_raster)
Fill_NCALM.save("Filled_raster")

rastercalc_temp = Raster("Filled_raster") - Raster("Clipped_raster")
rastercalc_temp.save("rastercalc_temp")
```

I have noticed that Clipped_raster and Fill_raster differ by 1 pixel depending on the options for Clip_management. However, I played around with the various possibilities with the same result.

Comment: You set the extent environment to `Aguada_rectangular_boundaries` but do not explain what this is in your question. Also if you look at the [sample code](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm#C_GUID-D4B6E476-CD4C-4BAD-A082-F698D0CDEDA6) for the Clip tool they explicitly set the extent parameter, try that instead of inheriting from the environment?

Comment: The clips work fine. My problem is the subtraction in the next to last line. Rastercalc_temp raster become exceeding large and the differences do not fall within Clipped_rast or Fill_NCALM

Comment: Also Aguada_rectangular_boundaries is a small rectangular shapefile the clips a small portion of the entire raster to speed processing.

Comment: One thing to explore is the extent property of your shapefile which you use to set the environment. Depending upon how you created 'Aguada_rectangular_boundaries' the extent of the data can become out of sync with your dataset extent. In arccatalog, go to properties of shapefile and click the recalculate extent under feature extent tab. That may help?

Comment: Thanks for responding but that is not the problem. I have found a clue though. When I set the Environment Processing Extent to Default before running the program, it works fine. However, if I set it to different extents and then include arcpy.env.extent = "Default" in Line 7 of the above, it fails. So it is an Extent problem, not sure why setting it in the program is not working.